# Angular 5 nested returns

Tags: javascript, angular5

i am trying to create a function that should return a boolean after calling my API

so i created the following function:

```
verify() {
    console.log('lol');
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) as User;
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'Users/' + user.id,
        {params: ApiHelperService.prototype.createParams([], true)}).subscribe(
        result => {
            return true;
        },
        error => {
            return false;
        }
    );

}
```

And then i called it:

```
if (this._userService.verify()) {
    return true;
}
else {
    this._router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
    return false;
}
```

However, sadly the function returns before the response from the server.

So my question is how can I create these nested return statements to make sure it returns the correct value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suggest you make use of async/await way like as below

```
async verify() {
    console.log('lol');
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) as User;
    return await this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'Users/' + user.id,
        {params: ApiHelperService.prototype.createParams([], true)})
    ).toPromise();
}
```

use it like this

```
async verifyoutput()
{
    try
    {
      const verify = await verify();
      return true;
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
verify():Observable<any> {
    console.log('lol');
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) as User;
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + 'Users/' + user.id,
    {params: ApiHelperService.prototype.createParams([], true)})
}

...

verify().subscribe(result => {
    return true
},err => {
    this._router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
    return false;
})
```